# .NET : XmlAttribute in Derived class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize big class that containes few collections of instances of classes that derive form same base class. Base class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Column))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Beam))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(FloorTruss))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(PanelBar))]
public abstract class BarBase
{
    #region Constructors

    public BarBase(int id, BarType barType)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.BarType = barType;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    [XmlAttribute]
    public BarType BarType
    {
        get
        {
            return barType;
        }
        set
        {
            barType = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private int id;

    private BarType barType;

}
```

Contains two XmlAttributes. Derived class :

```
public class Column : BarBase
{
    public Column()
        : base(0, BarType.BT_Invalid)
    {
        this.position = "";
        this.shortName = "";
    }


    public Column(int id, BarType barType, string position, string shortName)
        : base(id, barType)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Position
    {
        get
        {
            return position;
        }
    }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return shortName;
        }
    }

    private readonly string position;
    private readonly string shortName;
}
```

Adds another two. I have big class that stores few collections of derived classes. When i want to serialize them using

```
    public static string Serialize(Structure structure, string xmlFilePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Structure));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, structure);
        var result = builder.ToString();
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath);
        file.WriteLine(result);
        file.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Collections declared as:

```
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Column))]
    public List<Column> Columns
    {
        get
        {
            return columns;
        }
        set
        {
            columns = value;
        }
    }
```

Are being serialized as collections of base class instances - fields declared as XmlAttribute in Column class are not being serialized. Could anyone please explain me why this occurs ? How to make XmlAttributes in derived classes also being serializable ?

Many Thanks,

Comment: i have tried the above code and it all works fine. I created a list of three columns and it serialized to three "Column" nodes with the two attributes included

Comment: I also tried a List<BarBase> and added a Column and a Beam and I got a <Column /> and a <Beam /> node. Is that what you want to do?